# Check for unique elements of csv

Tags: python

I would like to check for duplicates in a .csv (structure bellow). Every value in this .csv has to be unique! You can find "a" thrice, but it should be there only once.

```
###start
a
a;b;
d;e
f;g
h
i;
i
d;b
a

c;i

### end
```

The progress so  far:

```
import os,glob
import csv
folder_path = "csv_entities/"
found_rows = set()

for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.csv")):
    with open(filepath) as fin, open("newfile.csv", "w") as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=";")
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            # delete empty list elements
            if "" in row:
                row = row[:-1]
            #delete empt row
            if not row:
                continue
            row = tuple(row)  # make row hashable 
            # don't write if row is there already!
            if row in found_rows:
                continue
            print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
            found_rows.add(row)
```

Which results in this csv:

```
###start
a

a;b

d;e

f;g

h

i

d;b

c;i

###end
```

The most important question is right now: How can I get rid of the double values?

e.g in the second row there should be only "b" instead of "a;b", because "a" is already in the row before.

Comment: use `open("newfile.csv", "w", newline="")` to get rid of the extra blank lines.

Comment: your method works for entire rows. extend your set for individual values and filter out the new rows instead.

Comment: What happens to line 3 (which has `a;b`)?  Does that just become `;b`?

Comment: @MarkMoretto, it shuld be just b then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mistake is to consider the *rows* themselves as unique elements. You have to consider cells as elements.

So use your marker set to mark *elements*, not *rows*.

Example with only one input file (using several input files with only one output file makes no sense)

```
found_values = set()

with open("input.csv") as fin, open("newfile.csv", "w",newline="") as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        # delete empty list elements & filter out already seen elements
        new_row = [x for x in row if x and x not in found_values]
        # update marker set with row contents
        found_values.update(row)
        if new_row:
            # new row isn't empty: write it
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

the resulting csv file is:

```
a
b
d;e
f;g
h
i
c
```